# Disable codeigniter error page for specific directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

my CodeIgniter project is located at www.mydomain.com/project

For that Custom 404 error page is working fine, that I've configured by writing following line in `routes.php`

```
$route ['404_override'] = 'content/not_found/'; //Here, content is controller, not_found() is method to handle 404 error.
```

I've one sub directory under my codeigniter project named **sub_project**, i.e `www.mydomain.com/project/sub_project`

I want to use `custom_404.html` for my **sub_project** (which is not coded in CodeIgniter framework). For that  I found an example of `.htaccess` to set 404 error page.

I created File: `/project/sub_project/.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /project/sub_project/custom_404.html
```

Now, What happends for my `sub_project` is, Its showing me `www.mydomain.com/content/not_found/` error page instead `custom_404.html`

Directory structure:

```
 www.mydomain.com
                |--/project                             (CodeIgniter)
                |--/project/applications/routes.php     (routes.php location)
                |--/project/sub_project                 (Other project in core PHP)
                |--/project/sub_project/.htaccess       (.htaccess location)
                |--/project/sub_project/custom_404.html (New error page)
```

Comment: Down-voters should left comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
RewriteEngine on 
ErrorDocument 404 /project/sub_project/custom_404.html
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but Its not working.
I think "/" will make it absolute path so apache will look for custom_404.html at root of my www directory. (www.mydomain.com/)

Comment: then try writing a custom message within htaccess file and see if it works. write- ErrorDocument 404 "Ooops, that page was <b>not found</b>. Please try a different one "

Comment: Ok. then do some quick testing. tell me what server you are using.   _ **By default, Ubuntu's Apache will ignore the directives in your .htaccess files. ** _  To enable .htaccess, you need to make changes in your apache configurations. first of all, check whether your .htaccess is working or not.

Comment: I'm using CentOS, Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4

Yes, I can confirm that .htaccess is working because I've rewrote URLs to remove index.php from all URLs of codeigniter.

Comment: lolz!! okk. try this- RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 "error happened"

Comment: Thanks @sunny
It solved my problem. :)
You may edit your answer so that I can mark it as an answer.